# Let's *not* delete questions that still have value

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Consider [Why does IntelliJ IDEA compile Scala so slowly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606591/why-does-intellij-idea-compile-scala-so-slowly), which until its deletion was the most accurate  and readable insight into Scala compiler performance on the entire Internet.

Or consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid, which until its deletion garnered hundreds of upvotes, and dozens of popular and laboriously detailed answers.

I'm not disputing that these don't fit the scope of Stack Overflow as it is currently defined.

**But I can't help but feel that deleting these questions and answers is throwing away a massive amount of user time and valuable information.**

Though these questions aren't currently the purpose of Stack Overflow, the posts that already exist have value, and huge numbers of people have said they were well-researched and useful.

---

It's impossible to tell how often such popular answers disappear from the site, since they are no longer indexed, and [cease to exist](http://blog.codinghorror.com/if-its-not-in-google-does-your-website-really-exist/). I noticed these two only because they are linked elsewhere, and I refer to them frequently as my favorite resources on these topics.

We don't want people creating off-topic questions and answers, but "closed" is a great way of indicating that question not a good example for future questions, while not throwing away the significant value it adds.

Let's delete questions and answers only when they are poor quality (not merely off-topic), as in "This is not useful, it reflects poorly on Stack Overflow, and isn't worth the bytes it was written with."

[Hidden Features of C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c) is clearly off-topic as defined by the Help Center. But it is useful and interesting enough that is has been closed and locked, not deleted.

---

Rather than calling everything trash and refactoring (deleting) every time we find a question that doesn't meet the latest and greatest criteria, let's consider the value a closed and read-only version would still provide.

I doubt very, very few questions with, say, 20 or more votes, are terrible enough that we all would be better off if they just disappeared from human history.

Comment: This does bring up an interesting question about the transitory nature of what is "on topic" at SO.  What is on topic one day might not be the next, and might again be on topic 6 months later... In which case, we have lost the original content due to a housecleaning that was eventually reversed.  A lot of noise is made about link-only answers going stale, indicating that SO wants to be an authority of information.. but if that information is periodically jettisoned due to prevailing winds of change in the "off topic" rules, it seems we could lose a lot of good content over time.

Comment: Does the licensing allow people to host those questions themselves?  Or could StackExchange set up a "closed but useful" site and migrate stuff over there?

Comment: Yes, the license allows it, @DanBeale. See [Unofficial Stack Overflow deleted question archive now available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124850), [Building an archive of deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122249), and note that there are any number of sites [which repost SE material with attribution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/).

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch this is a long known issue, there is even a special feature intended to deal with it, called [historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/historical-lock/info): "A historical lock preserves older content that was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of scope for the site it is posted on. Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted, and is often the final state of a question that has been deleted and undeleted more than once..."

Comment: @gnat, Yes!, that's what is needed!

Comment: // , Weird how much downvote this got. Let's not delete it, because, you know, it still has value.

Comment: I wouldn't mind this, if only the historical lock weren't such a massive effort to achieve every time someone finds a suitable candidate.

Comment: @TylerH you mean backwards, right? Here we "historically lock" 2 months old questions...

Comment: @Braiam No, I mean every time it seems someone wants a question locked for historical significance, the goal post moves and we have to both flag and ask on meta and argue with a CM and then find some sympathetic moderator in chat.

Comment: @TylerH what? Numbers? Remember [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710045/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-css)? Locked almost immediately someone complained on meta.

Comment: The irony is the sheer volume of questions that have no value and/or are duplicates that never get deleted on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You know what... meh.

The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid has been deleted for so long and apparently the internet [has adapted to that](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+common+mistakes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). There are at least 4 sites that are not Stack Overflow offering the same information you were trying to "keep". And that's good! It means that SO doesn't need to compromise its own guidelines to scratch that itch. I don't see anyone asking that question again on Stack Overflow. MISSION COMPLETE!

Now, instead of dedicating resources to keep cruft on the site that doesn't belong, dedicate resources to searching for a home where they belong and can cuddle the intellectual curiosity of the one that wants it.

Comment: "dedicate resources to keep those cruft on the site" It's always on the site; it's just more exclusive.

Comment: @PaulDraper For the vast majority of visitors, it is effectively off the site. Otherwise you wouldn't have posted your question in the first place...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's not on the site for the purposes of being useful, but it *is* on the site in regards to taking up server resources. Mostly hard drive space, granted, but it's not gone.

Answer (score -3):

So, let me start first by saying that I don't necessarily agree with you;  I'm just playing Devil's Advocate.

At a quick glance, the first question is rather dated as IntelliJ 9 isn't supported anymore, and the second question is just a checklist of pitfalls and gotchas.

While the first question does contain a great answer about the performance of Scalac, I feel like it doesn't belong there; a nice CW post with attribution to Martin Odersky would probably suffice as an explanation as to the performance of Scalac.  (The best part about that answer is that it doesn't mention the tool at all, so it can definitely apply to a broader audience.)

The second answer makes me quite uncomfortable to consider reopening, as now one would use that as impetus to justify *any* language's "pitfalls and best practices" question out there.  (If you think I'm making this up, this is why we're here right now, after all.)

It would likely get a historical lock like the C++ question, and no one would be able to contribute any extra information to it.  Keeping it maintained if the lock was fought off would also be a nightmare, but the Scala community would have to decide if they wanted to have that undertaking.  I'm not a part of that community so I can't say if there's enough energy to keep a list like that well-maintained.

It may be the case that we are losing a lot of valuable information in this way, but the platform has changed.  I earnestly feel that if the community feels that questions like this should still remain, then they've got to both prove that they're worthy and strive to have them maintain the standard of questions that we want going forward.

So, like I said, I'm not necessarily agreeing with you. You'll have to convince me that reopening/locking these questions is entirely worth it.  (Although, you could just repost the first answer with a question about Scalac's compiler performance. That'd be fine with me personally.)

Comment: "It would likely get a historical lock like the C++ question, and no one would be able to contribute any extra information to it."...yep, that'd be great. If that was indeed the right approach the C++ question (and I believe it was), then it would fit the Scala one.

Comment: "While the first question does contain a great answer about the performance of Scalac, I feel like it doesn't belong there" The question was rather specific about the OP's use case (IDEA 9); it happens that the correct answer is broader than that particular circumstance. That happens frequently. Many duplicate questions are closed for other questions that wouldn't ostensibly  answer that one (at least, not to someone that didn't already know the answer), but nonetheless does.

Comment: "You'll have to convince me that reopening/locking". I'm not trying to. I'm trying to convince you they should be **undeleted**. Leaving them closed to answers, comments, votes, etc. is fine with me.

Comment: Just an update: the first question was merged with another that asks "can I make Scala compile faster and will scalac ever be as fast as javac.", the answer is "no"; the second has been deleted for a long time, nobody has complained; third has been locked for a long time.