# Can I update defunct URLs on a post that is locked with historical significance?

Tags: support, locked-posts, historical-lock

I noticed that one of my old questions has a couple of broken links.  I would like to update the links in the question, however it has been locked with "historical significance" so I am not able to fix these broken links.

Could someone help me to update the links in the question?

- I have re-hosted the image of the tournament results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvZIT.jpg
- The broken link to Battleship.zip can be replaced with this Bitbucket project: https://bitbucket.org/otac0n/battleship
- CodePlex is shutting down, so I am moving my old tournaments code to GitHub: https://github.com/otac0n/tournaments

Comment: that QA should just be deleted dude.  it has almost no relationship to SO

Comment: Is there some reason you chose not to host that image on the StackExchange Imgur...?

Comment: @jpmc26: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631414/what-is-the-best-battleship-ai) is from 2009. Stack Exchange's imgur account [didn't exist until 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The image has been *rehosted*. If you're reuploading it anyway, why not upload it to a location dedicated for this site? That's the question I asked.

Comment: ["philosophically Historical Lock questions are **deleted**"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302852/839601 "quote source")

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot edit a locked post under any circumstances. However, a moderator can.

So…I've made what I believe to be the requested updates to [the question Makoto linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631414/what-is-the-best-battleship-ai).

The idea of a historical lock is really to keep these things frozen in time and *not* to try and maintain them, but since the entire thing arguably becomes completely useless with the links dead, and since you've already gone through the effort of putting the edit together, I figured it won't do any harm to make these changes.

A custom moderator flag probably would have worked, too, depending on which moderator had handled it and how carefully you described what you wanted.

But whether a flag or a Meta post, please don't try and make a regular habit of this. Consider it a one-off favor. :-)

Comment: I'm *really* not seeing the value in editing this question.  Like, genuinely *straining* to see why editing this would be a good idea. I'll defer to your judgment for now, but I'm seeking enlightenment.

Comment: @Makoto we can always do both: first we fix, then we dump the json to archive.org, then we delete.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not seeing the harm. It wasn't difficult to do, so why not? If you want to have a discussion about deleting the question entirely, then that's fine, but that really has nothing to do with whether or not this edit is made.

Comment: @CodyGray, the situation is straightforward, the QA should be deleted.  it does seem a bit weird (just one bloke's opinion) that you bother to edit it, since it's going to be deleted.  I mean the next thing people will be saying is "Oh, Cody himself edited it, let's not delete it"

Comment: @Fattie: Well, it's not going to get deleted unless a ♦ mod deletes (or unlocks) it, since it's locked. And I doubt a mod is going to delete it, since it looks like a perfect example of [what historical locking is meant for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for).

Comment: I don't see *harm* either, but I don't see *value*.  Perhaps when I've got a bit more time I'll actually drum up a discussion about its removal.

Answer (score 10):

[You mean *this* one, right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631414/what-is-the-best-battleship-ai)

I really don't think this needs to be updated.  It's not a fit for the current site anymore for these reasons:

- It's overly subjective ("best")
- It's a competition which offers bounties as rewards, which doesn't rub people the right way often
- There's really no further value in updating any of the information; in fact, because it's out of date, it's a better candidate to be removed from the site

I'd recommend that it not be maintained.  It's just not a fit here.  I'd support its removal though.  If you want to maintain the tournament then you could do so through some other platform/medium instead.

Comment: The question does have 52K views. In my opinion, there's a big difference between not actively maintaining it and not keeping the information up to date, and making sure the links are not dead to keep the post the same. It's a bad practice to have 404s on the site, because someone might buy the domain (if it's generating clicks) and might post god knows what on there.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth wait, isn't the worst practice keeping low quality post on the site?

Comment: @Braiam there are multiple high-view questions that aren't good questions for the site in it's current form, but are locked for historical significance. This question is one of them. That's why this is a problem, and why it can't be edited. I really agree with this policy, since other sites might link to it and it stays available, but there's a clear message that this isn't a good, on-topic question. That's why the views are relevant and I mentioned them in my first comment.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth so, become popular and throw quality out the window, right? Great!

Comment: @Braiam Nope, it's all about the "historical" part. It was a proper question then, but isn't now, but it has become a relevant part of the sites history (other sites and questions may refer to it, or it may have become relevant in some other way). That's why it gets to stay. If it wasn't a proper question then, it would've been deleted then.

Comment: Yeah, historical locks are problematic for like a hundred different reasons. The only thing worse is chaotic, unfettered deletion of a bunch of old, popular posts, breaking half of the Internet in the process.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth "proper question"??? Did at any moment competition was proper on SO? I know '09 was bad, but *that bad*?

Comment: @CodyGray "breaking half of the Internet" I think that was debunked when I have had deleted a bunch of questions and the [internet simply adapted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344757/792066).

Comment: @Braiam apparently, since it wasn't deleted back then. You could always try to develop time travel to clean up SO in the past and keep these bad questions from becoming part of SOs history

Comment: Related: support question asking for hard data to see if internet actually breaks. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333772/792066

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: 50K isn't all that significant to me.  Even more so in that it's really nothing new in terms of knowledge or useful information...it's just a contest.  No one would be harmed if this question were removed from Stack Overflow today and put on another site.  Nothing would break if this were the case.

Comment: It's not "just a contest". The answers provide solution to something that it's easy to imagine others wanting to implement. The question was also featured on Reddit, so that's a large amount of linkage. "put on another site" okay, what's your domain and access credentials so we can move it there?

Comment: what is all this bizarre agonizing?  just delete it

Comment: Don't delete content, especially since this can be moved to pcg.se just by slapping a [king-of-the-hill] tag on it.

Comment: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed." In other words, it is *known* to be a bad fit for SO. Nonetheless, it's a product of SO's "wild west" period, and its popularity is considered reason enough to leave it be. This question does a lot less harm than old software recommendation ones, which have lists of old software you probably shouldn't use.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Well, it could, except that questions older than 60 days can't be migrated.

Comment: @jpmc26 again the "be popular and rules doesn't matter anymore".

Comment: @Braiam: almost - be old and popular, and you'll be judged by the rules of your time. If a question is old and popular and isn't actively harmful (e.g. links to spam), it's maintained. You don't call the bulldozers to demolish the Tower of Pisa. Yes, we don't allow building leaning towers anymore - it's not a good idea for a lot of reasons. But it's not a good reason to destroy history, especially if it is the fruit of work of many people, and it turned out to be widely appreciated. What you do is to put it in safety and transform it into a museum, keep it clean and let people visit.

Comment: Locked questions are steam locomotives in a museum. We don't build them anymore, don't allow them to run on regular tracks, they have all kind of defects and you wouldn't really take one to go to work tomorrow morning. But they have their beauty, lots of people put a lot of work in them and we like to keep them around and watch them, even if they don't conform to current rules about safety or pollution. If some obtuse bureaucrat says that all steam locomotives must be destroyed because rules, he's just serving the rules for rules' sake, forgetting that they are in place to serve people.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I could not have put it better myself. Thank you. =)

Comment: @jpmc26:  I've seen historical locks justified on content which actually had some useful information in it.  I'm really, *really* not seeing anything useful for this.  Yes, it has a lot of views, but 50,000 in the span of almost eight years is ***not a lot of views***.  For context, [Hidden Features in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101268/1079354) has almost 600K views.  [Thinking in AngularJS with a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/1079354) has almost 750K views.  A question with 50K views from that long ago **wouldn't be missed.**

Comment: @MatteoItalia:  I'm going to refer you to my above comment directed at another commentator.  I'm not saying that there's anything wrong with putting antiques in a museum.  I'm saying that there's no value in putting *this* antique there.

Comment: @Makoto: This question is about Battleship AI algorithms. 50,000 views in the span of 8 years sure sounds like a lot to me, considering the extremely narrow topic compared to, say, something that would appeal to **every** Python programmer or anyone with jQuery experience working with Angular.

Comment: @BoltClock:  Still not convinced.  I plan on having a proper discussion about this at some future point.  I'm really not trying to be a jerk about this or anything.   I just remain unclear about the policy in which a diamond mod will update a locked post versus when they won't touch it.  It was always the impression that these posts *weren't* going to be touched since they were historical, but that doesn't seem to be the clear-cut case now.

Comment: @Makoto: Ah, funny you should say that... I was just having a heart-to-heart with a friend about matters that aren't always clear-cut :/

Comment: It should be pretty obvious that if a question is still providing use to visitors, then it should be kept up. Deleting questions that are still relevant to visitors is terrible UX.

Comment: There isn't a policy. If you ask nicely enough, and your request is reasonable, there's a good chance it will be granted. Sorry that I burst your bubble about strictly adhering to arbitrary rules, but I really don't operate that way.

Comment: @CodyGray:  The rule doesn't have to be *arbitrary*.  I'm okay with "at the moderator's discretion", but again since it's so rare I don't think it's ever come up.  All I'm looking for is clarity.  [Feel encouraged to add your comment as an answer on my support question, though.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356370/1079354)

Comment: Ugh. I didn't know it became a new Meta question. It gets tiring for people to obsessively try and create a policy out of every action that gets taken. Someone asked for [support], and I supported them.

Comment: @MatteoItalia "almost"? You absolutely sure? I've seen questions locked by "historical reasons" **72 hours old**. So, there's no almost, it's arbitrary and without any consideration towards *quality*, which, again, should be the *maxima* when deciding what to delete. Why nobody has tried to fix the question if they don't want it deleted? I mean, that's what SE says you should do. BTW, the lock was actually meant to prevent ping pongs deletions.

Comment: @Braiam: nobody has tried to fix the question because *you cannot fix it* - the very core of that question is off-topic for the current scope of Stack Overflow. The point is that you seem to think that you should delete by default unless the question is the most precious thing on the Internet. Quite the opposite; you should need a *serious* reason (offensive posts, spam or similar) to delete a question that was well tolerated at the time and where people spent hundred of man-hours. The total disregard for other people's work in the name of abstract purity that I see here drives me insane.

Comment: @MatteoItalia "because you cannot fix it" another fallacy. You can *fix* the question, what you cannot do is *edit the post*. You can extract the question from the post and post it somewhere else. That has been a solution SE has put forward for questions where too much work has to be done to savage the answers.

Comment: IMHO, *until* it *is* removed, it should be updated ... no reason to have broken links....